# Export an individual object for every frame of animation

Tags: rendering, animation, export

I am creating simple animations and need to know if I can export the individual frames as individual files to be rendered in a secondary rendering program? 
So I would need individual .obj or .3ds to import into Maxwell Render.

Comment: I think it would be more convenient to export these models with their animation together and render what desired. This may not work if accessible file format for import/export can't handle with armatures.

Answer (score 4):

You can export individual frame as individual obj files.
Goto>>File>>Export>>Wavefront (.obj)
Select a folder and then check animation checkmark on the left.then click Export OBJ

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Whatever is displayed in the 3D View is what will be exported. 
Choose the frame you want to export via the timeline view, or with the Left and Right arrow keys, and whatever pose the model is in will be how it will be exported.